# Group data by second?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data that looks like:

```
No. Time    Source  Destination Protocol    Length
1   0   192.168.6.132   192.168.6.149   RTPS    110
2   0.000008    192.168.6.132   192.168.154.1   RTPS    110
3   0.000013    192.168.6.132   192.168.221.1   RTPS    110
4   0.000021    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.149   RTPS    110
5   0.000025    192.168.6.132   192.168.154.1   RTPS    110
6   0.00003 192.168.6.132   192.168.221.1   RTPS    110
7   0.000133    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.149   RTPS    110
8   0.000149    192.168.6.132   192.168.154.1   RTPS    110
9   0.000153    192.168.6.132   192.168.221.1   RTPS    110
10  0.000158    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.149   RTPS    110
11  0.000162    192.168.6.132   192.168.154.1   RTPS    110
12  0.000166    192.168.6.132   192.168.221.1   RTPS    110
13  0.000195    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.114   RTPS    106
14  0.155988    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.114   RTPS    210
15  0.156002    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.125   RTPS    210
16  0.156008    192.168.6.132   192.168.70.1    RTPS    210
17  0.156014    192.168.6.132   192.168.80.1    RTPS    210
18  0.190113    192.168.6.149   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
19  0.191102    192.168.6.149   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
20  0.21706 192.168.6.149   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
21  0.26399 192.168.6.132   192.168.6.125   RTPS    210
22  0.264002    192.168.6.132   192.168.70.1    RTPS    210
23  0.264008    192.168.6.132   192.168.80.1    RTPS    210
24  0.264031    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.114   RTPS    210
25  0.323881    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.114   RTPS    106
26  0.408117    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
27  0.418088    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
28  0.426158    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
29  0.435039    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
30  0.453171    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
31  0.455198    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
32  0.459963    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.125   RTPS    210
33  0.459975    192.168.6.132   192.168.70.1    RTPS    210
34  0.459981    192.168.6.132   192.168.80.1    RTPS    210
35  0.459995    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.114   RTPS    210
36  0.470089    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
37  0.569183    192.168.6.149   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
38  0.718822    192.168.6.149   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
39  0.736077    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.114   RTPS    202
40  0.736102    192.168.6.132   192.168.80.1    RTPS    202
41  0.73611 192.168.6.132   192.168.70.1    RTPS    202
42  0.73612 192.168.6.132   192.168.6.125   RTPS    202
43  0.765126    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
44  0.837028    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.125   RTPS    210
45  0.837042    192.168.6.132   192.168.70.1    RTPS    210
46  0.837047    192.168.6.132   192.168.80.1    RTPS    210
47  0.837061    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.114   RTPS    210
48  0.895085    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
49  0.919585    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
50  0.95995 192.168.6.132   192.168.6.125   RTPS    202
51  0.959959    192.168.6.132   192.168.70.1    RTPS    202
52  0.959965    192.168.6.132   192.168.80.1    RTPS    202
53  0.959986    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.114   RTPS    202
54  0.985993    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.125   RTPS    202
55  0.98601 192.168.6.132   192.168.70.1    RTPS    202
56  0.986023    192.168.6.132   192.168.80.1    RTPS    202
57  0.986216    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.114   RTPS    202
58  0.991958    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.125   RTPS    202
59  0.991967    192.168.6.132   192.168.70.1    RTPS    202
60  0.991971    192.168.6.132   192.168.80.1    RTPS    202
61  0.991991    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.114   RTPS    202
62  1.069143    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.125   RTPS    202
63  1.069178    192.168.6.132   192.168.70.1    RTPS    202
64  1.069197    192.168.6.132   192.168.80.1    RTPS    202
65  1.069236    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.114   RTPS    202
66  1.1095  192.168.6.149   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
67  1.109993    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.114   RTPS    202
68  1.110006    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.125   RTPS    202
69  1.110012    192.168.6.132   192.168.70.1    RTPS    202
70  1.110017    192.168.6.132   192.168.80.1    RTPS    202
71  1.176661    192.168.6.114   239.255.0.1 RTPS    822
72  1.186424    192.168.6.149   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
73  1.24307 192.168.6.132   192.168.6.125   RTPS    110
74  1.2431  192.168.6.132   192.168.70.1    RTPS    110
75  1.24312 192.168.6.132   192.168.80.1    RTPS    110
76  1.243149    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.114   RTPS    110
77  1.307628    192.168.6.114   192.168.6.132   RTPS    106
78  1.314474    192.168.6.149   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
79  1.344895    192.168.6.149   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
80  1.372821    192.168.6.149   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
81  1.395822    192.168.6.114   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
82  1.425897    192.168.6.125   192.168.6.132   RTPS    106
83  1.802883    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    890
84  1.851153    192.168.6.149   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
85  1.878097    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    890
86  1.903379    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    890
87  1.998941    192.168.6.149   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
88  1.999752    192.168.6.149   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
89  2.010819    192.168.6.114   192.168.6.132   RTPS    218
90  2.012812    192.168.6.114   192.168.6.132   RTPS    218
91  2.029853    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.114   RTPS    110
92  2.02987 192.168.6.132   192.168.6.125   RTPS    110
93  2.029875    192.168.6.132   192.168.70.1    RTPS    110
94  2.02988 192.168.6.132   192.168.80.1    RTPS    110
95  2.048372    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
96  2.082863    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.125   RTPS    110
97  2.082881    192.168.6.132   192.168.70.1    RTPS    110
98  2.082889    192.168.6.132   192.168.80.1    RTPS    110
99  2.082913    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.114   RTPS    110
100 2.087518    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    910
101 2.102426    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
102 2.108882    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.125   RTPS    110
103 2.108894    192.168.6.132   192.168.70.1    RTPS    110
104 2.108899    192.168.6.132   192.168.80.1    RTPS    110
105 2.108916    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.114   RTPS    110
106 2.141479    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
107 2.163   192.168.6.132   192.168.6.125   RTPS    110
108 2.16304 192.168.6.132   192.168.70.1    RTPS    110
109 2.163061    192.168.6.132   192.168.80.1    RTPS    110
110 2.163144    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.114   RTPS    110
111 2.175276    192.168.6.114   192.168.6.132   RTPS    106
112 2.175668    192.168.6.114   192.168.6.132   RTPS    106
113 2.176194    192.168.6.114   192.168.6.132   RTPS    106
114 2.176196    192.168.6.114   192.168.6.132   RTPS    106
115 2.176724    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    890
116 2.186826    192.168.6.149   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
117 2.18683 192.168.6.149   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
118 2.187821    192.168.6.149   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
119 2.187825    192.168.6.149   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
120 2.202925    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.125   RTPS    110
121 2.202936    192.168.6.132   192.168.70.1    RTPS    110
122 2.202942    192.168.6.132   192.168.80.1    RTPS    110
123 2.202958    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.114   RTPS    110
124 2.204504    192.168.6.114   192.168.6.132   RTPS    106
125 2.217402    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    918
126 2.250785    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    910
127 2.253399    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
128 2.255321    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    906
129 2.277901    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.125   RTPS    110
130 2.277914    192.168.6.132   192.168.70.1    RTPS    110
131 2.27792 192.168.6.132   192.168.80.1    RTPS    110
132 2.277946    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.114   RTPS    110
133 2.27952 192.168.6.114   192.168.6.132   RTPS    106
134 2.303003    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.125   RTPS    110
135 2.303043    192.168.6.132   192.168.70.1    RTPS    110
136 2.303064    192.168.6.132   192.168.80.1    RTPS    110
137 2.303147    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.114   RTPS    110
138 2.304437    192.168.6.114   192.168.6.132   RTPS    106
139 2.314884    192.168.6.125   192.168.6.132   RTPS    106
140 2.314886    192.168.6.125   192.168.6.132   RTPS    106
141 2.314965    192.168.6.125   192.168.6.132   RTPS    106
142 2.31512 192.168.6.125   192.168.6.132   RTPS    106
143 2.315121    192.168.6.125   192.168.6.132   RTPS    106
144 2.315205    192.168.6.125   192.168.6.132   RTPS    106
145 2.315206    192.168.6.125   192.168.6.132   RTPS    106
146 2.320935    192.168.6.132   192.168.6.125   RTPS    110
147 2.32096 192.168.6.132   192.168.70.1    RTPS    110
148 2.320976    192.168.6.132   192.168.80.1    RTPS    110
149 2.32103 192.168.6.132   192.168.6.114   RTPS    110
150 2.329616    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
151 2.330565    192.168.6.114   192.168.6.132   RTPS    106
152 2.341503    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
153 2.343022    192.168.6.149   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
154 2.376308    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
155 2.395825    192.168.6.149   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
156 2.548168    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
157 2.570517    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
158 2.611479    192.168.6.125   192.168.6.132   RTPS    106
159 2.613891    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
160 2.618985    192.168.6.149   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
161 2.656532    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    922
162 2.736513    192.168.6.125   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
163 2.923952    192.168.6.114   192.168.6.132   RTPS    110
164 2.924452    192.168.6.114   192.168.6.132   RTPS    110
165 2.954357    192.168.6.132   239.255.0.1 RTPS    922
166 2.956826    192.168.6.149   239.255.0.1 RTPS    922
167 2.982879    192.168.6.149   239.255.0.1 RTPS    146
```

...

I need to group lengths by second. I need to know average length per second for each second.

For example:

```
if we have:
0.1 100
0.4 200
0.5 500
1.2 100
1.5 900
1.9 800
1.99 900
....
```

My output would be:

```
   Time  Length

    0    266.66
    1    675.00
```

My goal is to graph this resulting table to find out at which second did I have the most average bandwidth usage.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? In what way were the results different from what you wanted?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I don't know where to start... I have never done anything like this with Excel...

Comment: How do you want to define the seconds (round to nearest second, whole second thresholds, etc.)?

Comment: @fixer1234 No preference, FLOOR(second) is fine...

Comment: You've answered your own question. Use `FLOOR()` and make a pivot table.

Comment: No need to use FLOOR.  Just use a Pivot table and select to group the rows by `1`